# Binary cross-entropy: plugging in probability 0

Tags: cross-entropy

There is an answer on the Kaggle question board [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge/discussion/46673) by Dr. Fuzzy:

```
You can assess a total miss-classification szenario by plugging zero-probs in the log-loss 
function (here sklearn log-loss):

LL           Count    Class
3.31035117   15294    toxic
0.34523409    1595    severe_toxic
1.82876664    8449    obscene
0.10346200     478    threat
1.70495856    7877    insult 
0.30410902    1405    identity_hate

For some classes the possible LL for total miss-classification is really low.
In this range gradients might no longer provide meaningful directions.
Another point is that most log-loss implementations use clipping for probs near 0. 
This will play in here as well.
```

I understand this person is saying "if you never predict the class 'toxic', then what is the log loss?" And the answer is 3.31035117. My question is: how can you possibly get a non-infinite answer?

As far as I know, sklearn's logloss function is binary crossentropy.

The binary crossentropy function is (for a single label):

-( ylog(p) + (1-y)log(1-p) )

If the label is "toxic" (y=1), but we associate that with probability 0 (p=0), we should get:

-( 1log(0) + (1-1)log(1-0) ) = -( -inf + 0 ) = inf

Why are we not getting infinity here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dr. Fuzzy points out [sklearn's log-loss uses clipping](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html). This implies that it isn't putting a 0 in for $p$, but rather some small epsilon value. This is put in to avoid the infinities/weirdness associated with probability 0/1 that you noted.

Answer (score 1):

You should never get $p=0$ or $p=1$. The probabilities usually come from the models such as [logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression), where the odds ratio or log odds are modeled in regression. For instance, the logit model is:
$$\ln\frac p {1-p}=X\beta+\varepsilon$$
There's no way to get $p=0$ in logit in ideal world.

Of course, you can get 0 due to floating-point arithmetic artifacts. In this case you force the cross entropy into a large but non infinite number. It must be a terrible model if you're approaching zero where it should be 1. Hence very large likelihood should steer away your optimization from the parameters that lead to such a model.

Comment: One sharp corner to look out for is finite-precision arithmetic yielding 0.0

Comment: @Sycorax, yes, that's a concern, I didn't want to get into